# Escape quotes and equal to sign in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, html-escape-characters

I am renaming all files on my website with a "r-" ( r  hyphen ) prefix.

For example, contact.php will become r-contact.php

So I want to search and replace all href=" with href="r- inside my PHP files.

I am trying to write a script using preg_replace to achieve this. Is there a way to escape these special characters.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: This looks more like a job for a command line tool like `sed` than PHP.

Comment: @Jay I just tried preg_replace, but it outputs href=\"

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
preg_replace('/href="(.*?)"/i', 'href="r-$1"', $document);
```